# Appropriate class structuring c#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm needing some advice on structuring my classes for an application which models 6 different but similar types. The 6 types have some properties and methods they will all share. There are also properties and methods that 3, 4, or 5 of them will share but would have no meaning to the others.

Currently, I have an abstract base class with:

- properties and methods that all of the subclasses will use, already implemented.
- methods that some of the subclasses will use marked as abstract, to be implemented in the subclasses.
- properties that some of the subclasses will use marked as nullable so that subclasses in which the property would not be used it could be null.

This just doesn't seem like the best solution though. I feel like I have provided enough details, but if this doesn't make sense just let me know and I will try to provide a better description.

**EDIT -- adding code example**

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    //all classes inheriting from BaseClass would use these properties
    public string Property1{ get; set; }
    public string Property2{ get; set; }

    public void Method1() {
        //all classes inheriting from BaseClass would use this method
    }

    //more than one class (but not all classes) 
    //  inheriting from BaseClass would use these properties
    public int? Property3 { get; set; }
    public bool? Propert4 { get; set; }

    public abstract void Method2() {
        //more than one class (but not all classes) 
        //  inheriting from BaseClass would use this method

        //those not using this method would have empty getters and setters maybe?
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: You could have multiple abstract classes inheriting from a base class.

Comment: I added some sample code, its just a concept example. I can't think of a good parallel example and can't share my actual code. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This just doesn't seem like the best solution though. I feel like I have provided enough details, but if this doesn't make sense just let me know and I will try to provide a better description.

There is little detail, but it does sound like you'd be better off having a separate "layer" in your class hierarchy.

Classes 3, 4, and 5 could derive from a separate abstract class, which in turned inherited your "base" class.  This would eliminate the need for classes 1 and 2 to have the "unused" methods and properties in them.

Basically, the "properties that some of the subclasses will use marked as nullable so that subclasses in which the property would not be used it could be null" would not be in the base class, but rather added to a subclass, which in turn was subclasses for 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that intermediate layers would improve my situation, but even those layers have only partial shares, for example the classes 3, 4, and 5 you mentioned might have a good deal of commonality, but 5 would still differ by one or two properties while it works great for 3 and 4. What I'm getting at is this is heading towards a massive tree structure. Is this still a preferable approach?

Comment: @Ethan Yes, in general.  Having "unused" properties and methods is typically a sign of a real flaw in your design.  Try to avoid it, even if it means adding layers.  If class 5 is the only class using a property, just declare it there directly...

Comment: I kind of laughed at myself when I realized how bad of an example the one non-common property was, haha. Its a very complicated set of objects I'm trying to model. These classes relate to physical objects whose properties translate to physical attributes of the real life object. So my design comes just from the way these objects exist in the real world. I agree though, it sure doesn't lend itself to a simple representation in code.

Comment: @Ethan In general, I'd avoid "unused" members in types - even if it leads to a deeper hierarchy

Comment: Alrighty, thanks again for the help. Looks like I'm going to be doing a lot of diagramming today to see how I can break these out into more clear layers.

Comment: As I suspected, I now have the problem where some properties are shared between classes A and B, some between C and D, and then some more between B, C, and D, but not A.

Comment: @Ethan Often, this is a sign that you should look at encapsulation and interfaces instead of inheritance.  True "is-a" relationships tend to not exhibit this, as it tends to be more "behavioral" in nature (ie: "acts as" instead of "is a" type of relationships), which suggests interfaces are more appropriate

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should elaborate a hierarchy to avoid the use of nullables. You should create

1. an intermediate subclass containing the other common properties OR
2. declare an interface implementing the common properties, and having these classes implementing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Following this will lead to a massive tree structure of inheritance because the number of properties is in the dozens and the grouping of usage is not very uniform. Example: 3 classes might use all of the same properties except one or two, and and one of these classes might share a property from a different group. This would lead to a need for multiple base classes too.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can inherit like this?

```
                ****************************                          
                *                          *                          
                *         FooBase          *                          
                *                          *                          
                ****************************                          
                    .                 .
                   .                   .
                  .                     .
          **************            *****************                 
          *            *            *               *                 
          *   FooA     *            *    FooB       *                 
          *            *            *               *                 
          *            *            *               *                 
          **************            *****************                 
           .       .                           .                      
          .         .                           .                     
         .           .                           .                    
        .             .                           .                   
  **************   **************            **************           
  *            *   *            *            *            *           
  *            *   *            *            *            *           
  *  FooA_a    *   *   FooA_b   *            *  FooB_a    *           
  *            *   *            *            *            *           
  *            *   *            *            *            *           
  *            *   *            *            *            *           
  **************   **************            **************
```

So why add nullable properties when you can implement them in FooA instead of FooBase?

**EDIT**
And so [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507848/215042) and [Felice Pollano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507861/215042) beat me to it because I was drawing stuff :P

Comment: Thanks for the drawing :) it really helped to make sense of having intermediate layers. My problem with this though, is that FooB_a might have a lot of similarities with FooA_a and FooA_b also, which would make it need to inherit from FooA too. That would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Why use subclassing?  Let your abstract base class only have the methods that all your types share.  Pull other methods into separate class, let the classes that need that functionality collaborate with the extracted classes.  This creates better cohesion and looser coupling.

Comment: I see where you're going with this. It's just that classes A, B, and C might need Method1 and Method2, but only B and C might need Property1. These classes have dozens of properties and the classes that share properties and methods don't fall into groups large enough to facilitate making separate classes. In other words, separating the partially shared properties and methods into separate classes would result in a large number of abstract classes. This might just need to be the way I go though. (note: property names in this comment don't line up with the code I posted.)

Comment: A large number of classes is a good thing, not a bad thing.  It is a sign that you are adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Yes, but a large number of classes to represent only 6 different physical objects seems more like a hack when many of these classes wont exactly even have a Responsibility other than containing properties. I'm finding myself naming these classes with names like "AllButClassA" because there's no other descriptive way to name them. That's not sounding like a class with responsibilities. Not really disagreeing with you, just saying it doesn't feel much better- especially when it comes to readability and maintainability.

Comment: Maybe.  It's really hard to talk about this sort of thing with a generic problem statement; the cohesiveness and responsibilities can really only be seen through the lens of the problem domain.

Comment: Yeah I tried to come up with something to parallel what I'm actually facing that I could use as an example here, but I just couldn't think of anything that compared, and I can't give specifics about what I'm working on. Thanks for your efforts.